# How can I take an inut list from user in one function, and transfer the tuple data to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make this easier so the user wont have to re-input their data for a second time to get the results. It was easier for myself to separate the functions as they have two different purposes but if possible I don't want the user to have to re input data as it can be a long and tedious process to repeat.

```
def scores():
   ''' print('we are starting')
    count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: '))
    print('Each will be entered one per line')
    scoreList = []
    for i in range(1, count+1):
        scoreList.append(int(input('Enter score: '))) '''
for score in scoreList: 
    if score >= 91:
        print('A')
    elif score >= 81 and score <=90:
        print('B')
    elif score >= 71 and score <=80:
        print('C')
    elif score >= 61 and score <=70:
        print('D')
    else:
        print('F')
```

Within the quote section, that is what I have in the previous funtcion but Ive been fiddling with the idea of just targeting the scoreList and seeing if that will carry down to the next function but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 1):

Return the list from the first function, and accept the score list as a parameter for the second function.

```
def get_scores():
    print('we are starting')
    count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: '))
    print('Each will be entered one per line')
    scoreList = []
    for i in range(1, count+1):
        scoreList.append(int(input('Enter score: ')))
    return scoreList

def grade_scores(scoreList):
    for score in scoreList: 
        if score >= 91:
            print('A')
        elif score >= 81 and score <=90:
            print('B')
        elif score >= 71 and score <=80:
            print('C')
        elif score >= 61 and score <=70:
            print('D')
        else:
            print('F')

scores = get_scores()
grade_scores(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if you want to do this the **easy** way, or the **hard** but more beautiful way.

The easy escaping way would be defining a **global variable**, passing it into both functions so the user only has to enter once. You can use this for small programs or single projects.

However, the best way would be defining a `Score` or `Student` class, define methods then, create a **student instance** with a **score** assigned to it. Than you can call those methods on that student object.

For a beginner, using a global variable is maybe the best way, but **Classes** are important parts of Python and OOP, and one should learn it sooner than later.

Given in your question, you should probably unite them as a single function. Otherwise, as your question title suggests, use the result of the first function in the second one.